# Codeigniter: Pagination doesn't get other rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

MY CONTROLLER:

```
 $config['base_url'] = base_url('admin/profile?id=' . $profile_id);
  $config['total_rows'] = 1000;//count($data['getTime']);
  $config['per_page'] = 5; 
  $config['num_links'] = 2;
  //$config['uri_segment'] = 2;
  //$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
  $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
  $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
  $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
  $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

  $this->pagination->initialize($config);

  $page = ($this->uri->segment(5))? $this->uri->segment(5) : 0;
  $data['getTime'] = $this->admin->getUserProfileTime($profile_id, $config["per_page"], $page);
  $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
  //pagination
```

MY MODEL

```
  function getUserProfileTime($profile_id, $num, $page)
{
$this -> db -> select('*');
//$this -> db -> from('timerecord');
$this -> db -> where('id', $profile_id);
//-$this -> db -> order_by('dateToday', 'DESC');
$this -> db -> order_by('dateOrder', 'DESC');
$this -> db -> limit($num, $page);

$query = $this -> db -> get('timerecord');
//$array = $query->result_array();
return $query->result();

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
```

}

MY VIEWS

```
 <?php 
                foreach($getTime as $row): 
                $timeStat = $row->status;
                $approveStat = $row->ApprovalStat;
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td class="tn-ixdt"><?php echo $row->year_Int ?></td>
                <td class="tn-ixdt"><?php echo $row->dateToday ?></td>
                <td class="tn-ixdt"><?php echo $row->day ?></td>
                <td class="tn-ixdt" style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row->day_Int ?></td>
                <td class="tn-ixdt"><?php echo $row->timeIn ?></td>
                <td class="tn-ixdt"><?php echo $row->timeOut ?></td>
                <td class="tn-ixdt"><?php echo $row->status ?></td>
              </tr>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
              </table><br />
            <div align="center"><?php echo $links; ?></div>
```

Hi there, my pagination is not working properly, it shows the first 5 right records, but when i clicked the pagination links it doesn't go to the other rows, is it the problem is in my url query? my url is like this admin/profile?id=1&per_page=65, the page number is also correct, but it still don't get the other records from my table. please, i need your help guys! thanks!

Comment: try to print the raw query built when you hit the next page, see wht's wrong there

Comment: what do you mean raw query built? mr. ngakak?

Comment: raw query resulted from your active record

Comment: hi mr. ngakak, i think here is my error the uri segment because when 
i change the $page to number "1" it works perfectly kindly check the code. thanks and if you can provide answer to this misery i'll be very thankful to you mr.ngakak

$page = ($this->uri->segment(2))? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

$data['getTime'] = $this->admin->getUserProfileTime($profile_id, $config["per_page"], 1);

Comment: what is the result of this  $page = ($this->uri->segment(5))? $this->uri->segment(5) : 0;  everytime you hit next page ? if smth is wrong then thts the problem

Comment: no result mr. ngakak, the query result doesn't change it is stuck at first 10 row of my table, thanks!, can i include hashtag in my url after the per_page? where should i put this #page on my controller section? thanks!

Comment: I is the number printed by this : $page = ($this->uri->segment(5))? $this->uri->segment(5) : 0; verytime you hit next page ?.

yes you can . just add to the anchor . anchor(site_url('blog/post/'.$post->title)."#comments");

Answer (score 0):

because your using wrong table.. try to add this to your controller

```
$this->load->library('table');
```

and in your view, to see your table.. here is the code

```
$this->table->set_heading('header1', 'header2', 'header3','header4'); //this is just the table heading

//in this code, you are looping your table row and the database informatio
    foreach ($products->result() as $row) { 


        $this->table->add_row(
            $row->column1,
            $row->column2,
            $row->column3,
            $row->column4
        );
    }


    echo $this->table->generate();
```

and this code of your model, remove the ->result(), it should be

```
    foreach ($query as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
```

Comment: still out of luck mr. codeslayer, here is the output

 < 1 2 3
header1 header2 header3 header4
2014 September 1, 2014 Monday 9:21 am
2014 September 1, 2014 Monday 9:21 am
2014 September 1, 2014 Monday 9:21 am
2014 September 1, 2014 Monday 9:21 am
2014 September 1, 2014 Monday 9:21 am
 < 1 2 3

Comment: don't put the out put here..edit your answer and add the output..and comment here after your done editing to notify me